# Ensure the class is annotated with Introspected

Tags: jhipster, micronaut, hibernate-envers

My class:

```
/**
 * A Customer.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Audited
@Introspected
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    @Column(name = "uuid", length = 36, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private UUID uuid;
}
```

I call:

```
Customer result = customerRepository.save(cust);
```

Even if I use `@Introspected` annotation in my `Pojo` class `Customer`, Error I get:

`Unexpected error occurred: Unable to perform beforeTransactionCompletion callback: No bean introspection available for type [class org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity]. Ensure the class is annotated with io.micronaut.core.annotation.Introspected`

All tables related audit is created.

Using Jhipster + Micronaut + Hibernate Envers

Below is my setup info:

```
MHipster v1.0.2 :: Running Micronaut v2.4.4
JHipster version: 6.10.5
```

Comment: So what is your question? The error message is pretty obvious, did you try its recommendation?

Comment: Yes, Let me update the class here.

Comment: error message mentions a class from hibernate-envers, did you check that hibernate-envers is supported by Micronaut?

Comment: Yes, It does support hibernate-envers.

Comment: OK, then you should probably report them a bug

Comment: Ok, I am trying to find if someone else got into the same issue and solved it.

Comment: Error Reported: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/6221

Comment: Since this bug was already fixed, try upgrading your app to 3.0.x (or at least the latest 2.5.x)

Comment: @BurtBeckwith I am using below setup 
MHipster v1.0.2 :: Running Micronaut v2.4.4
JHipster version: 6.10.5

Comment: You can try to upgrade to 3.x or latest 2.5.x. There are open issues in mhipster side for that. I think updating one application should be fine, we struggle most oft the times with all options we support. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster-micronaut/issues/259

Comment: Let me give it a try. Thanks. @atomfrede

Comment: @atomfrede I am using this https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster-micronaut, and it says it supports Micronaut 2.4.4

Comment: Yes it supports (=generates micronaut 2.4.4) but you can modify your application afterwards (but of course loosing the posibility to update anything via jhipster without replaying your changes again until the blueprint has been updated).